# Parslet Alternatives Not parsing whole string

Tags: ruby, parslet

I have the following specs

```
  it "parses a document with only an expression" do
    puts parser.document.should parse("[b]Hello World[/b]")
  end
  it "parses a document with only text" do
    puts parser.document.should parse(" Hello World")
  end
  it "parses a document with both an expression and text" do
    puts parser.document.should parse("[b]Hello World[/b] Yes hello")
  end
```

For the following Parslet Parser

```
class Parser < Parslet::Parser

rule(:open_tag) do
  parslet = str('[')
  parslet = parslet >> (str(']').absent? >> match("[a-zA-Z]")).repeat(1).as(:open_tag_name)
  parslet = parslet >> str(']')
  parslet
end

rule(:close_tag) do
  parslet = str('[/')
  parslet = parslet >> (str(']').absent? >> match("[a-zA-Z]")).repeat(1).as(:close_tag_name)
  parslet = parslet >> str(']')
  parslet
end

rule(:text) { any.repeat(1).as(:text) }

rule(:expression) do
  # [b]Hello World[/b]
  # open tag, any text up until closing tag, closing tag
  open_tag.present?
  close_tag.present?
  parslet = open_tag >> match("[a-zA-Z\s?]").repeat(1).as(:enclosed_text) >> close_tag
  parslet
end

rule(:document) do
  expression | text
end
```

The first two tests pass just fine, and I can see by `put`ing them out to the command line that the atoms are of the correct type. However, when I try to parse a document with both an expression and plain text, it fails to parse the plain text, failing with the following error

```
Parslet::UnconsumedInput: Don't know what to do with " Yes hello" at line 1 char 19.
```

I think I'm missing something regarding defining the :document rule. What I want is something that will consume any number of in sequence expressions and plain text, and while the rule I have will consume each atom individual, using them both in the same string causes failure.

Comment: For RSpec, you generally use #should, and you probably don't want #puts.

Comment: It is using should, I just had some puts statements snuck in whilst I was experimenting.

Comment: Gotcha -- didn't see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your `document` rule you want to use [`repeat`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/parslet/Parslet/Atoms/DSL#repeat-instance_method):

```
rule(:document) do
  (expression | text).repeat
end
```

You’ll also need to change your `text` rule; currently if it starts matching it will consume everything including any `[` that should start a new `expression`. Something like this should work:

```
rule(:text) { match['^\['].repeat(1).as(:text) }
```

Comment: I ended up coming to the same conclusion, ended up moving the expression | text decision into another rule called section and document called section.repeat(1)

Answer (score 4):

What you were looking for is something like this...

```
require 'parslet'

class ExampleParser < Parslet::Parser
  rule(:open_tag) do
    str('[') >> 
      match["a-zA-Z"].repeat(1).as(:open_tag_name) >>
    str(']')
  end
```

The open_tag rule doesn't need to exclude the ']' character as the match only allows letters.

```
  rule(:close_tag) do
    str('[/') >> 
      match["a-zA-Z"].repeat(1).as(:close_tag_name) >>
    str(']')
  end
```

same here

```
  rule(:text) do 
    (open_tag.absent? >> 
      close_tag.absent? >> 
        any).repeat(1).as(:text) 
  end
```

If you exclude the open and close tags here.. you know you are only dealing with text. 
Note: I like this technique of using "any" once you have excluded the things you don't want, but bare it in mind if you are refactoring later as your exclusion list may need to grow.
Note2: You could simplify this further as below..

```
  rule(:text) do 
    (str('[').absent? >> any).repeat(1).as(:text) 
  end
```

.. if you don't want any square brackets in your text at all.

```
  rule(:expression) do
    # [b]Hello World[/b]
    open_tag >> text.as(:enclosed_text) >> close_tag
  end
```

This becomes much simpler as the text can't include a close_tag

```
  rule(:document) do
    (expression | text).repeat
  end
```

I've added in the repeat you missed (as pointed out by matt)

```
end

require 'rspec'
require 'parslet/rig/rspec'

describe 'example' do
  let(:parser) { ExampleParser.new }
  context 'document' do
    it "parses a document with only an expression" do
      parser.document.should parse("[b]Hello World[/b]")
    end
    it "parses a document with only text" do
      parser.document.should parse(" Hello World")
    end
    it "parses a document with both an expression and text" do
      parser.document.should parse("[b]Hello World[/b] Yes hello")
    end
  end
end


RSpec::Core::Runner.run([])
```

Hope this give you some tips on using Parslet. :)